# Camel Salesforce Component can't find Platform Event object

Tags: apache-camel, salesforce

I have used `camel-salesforce-maven-plugin` to generate the DTO and have successfully created a Contact record. However, when I tried to emit an event following [docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/salesforce-component.html).

I received the following error:

```sh
2020-05-21 13:30:47.844 ERROR 4276 --- [ent@3c50ad4b-22] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-DESKTOP-UO2CP5I-1590033642730-0-7 on ExchangeId: ID-DESKTOP-UO2CP5I-1590033642730-0-7). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.api.NoSuchSObjectException: {errors:[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist","fields":null}],statusCode:404}

Message History (complete message history is disabled)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[moodle-event      ] [moodle-event      ] [from[timer://hello?period=2000]                                               ] [        81]
        ...
[moodle-event      ] [to3               ] [salesforce:createSObject?sObjectName=Moodle__e                                ] [         0]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.api.NoSuchSObjectException: {errors:[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist","fields":null}],statusCode:404}
        at org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.internal.client.DefaultRestClient.createRestException(DefaultRestClient.java:110) ~[camel-salesforce-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.internal.client.AbstractClientBase$1.onComplete(AbstractClientBase.java:231) ~[camel-salesforce-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:218) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:210) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:543) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:523) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.responseSuccess(HttpReceiver.java:486) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.messageComplete(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:326) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseFields(HttpParser.java:1161) ~[jetty-http-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1534) ~[jetty-http-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.parse(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:200) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:141) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:75) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:133) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:156) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:543) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:398) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:161) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
```

Here are the code I used:

```java
from("timer:hello?period={{timer.period}}").routeId("moodle-event")
    .noStreamCaching()
    .process(exchange ->{
        final Message in = exchange.getIn();

        /*Contact con = new Contact();
        con.setFirstName("Maven");
        con.setLastName("Camel");
        con.setEmail("maven.camel@gmail.com");
        con.setMobilePhone("+61466879506");
        */
        
        Moodle__e evt = new Moodle__e();
        evt.setData__c("Data from Camel");          
        in.setBody(evt);
    })
    .to("salesforce:createSObject?sObjectName=Moodle__e");
```

I have created this `Moodle__e` in Salesforce with only one field `Data__c` of `String` type and have successfully tested this event with other client app.

Comment: Did you manage this somehow? I have the same problem with querying.

Comment: @MaciekLeks I set the api version
to 48 which was my sandbox version and it worked. I set it in my application.properties file: camel.component.salesforce.api-version=48.0

Comment: @MaciekLeks Also I use Camel 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT version from repository. Hope this helps

Comment: true I've discovered it later the day I wrote the comment, that the apiVersion was set to 50.0 but camel-salesforce does not like it. Cheers.